# JRuby JSR223 Interface ignores binidngs

Tags: binding, jruby, jsr223

It seems that the JSR 223 javax.script interface of the JRuby (1.6.7.2) framework ignores bound Java values in the Bindings of a ScriptContext.
Do I make a mistake?
Here is a simple example that doesn't work:

```
private void run() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine engine = new JRubyEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
    LittleClass l = new LittleClass();
    engine.put("l", l);
    engine.eval("l.x;");
}

public class LittleClass {
    public int x;
    public void add() {
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
```

Or is this a known problem?

Comment: I get the following error:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `l' for main:Object
  (root) at <script>:1

Answer (score 3):

By default, local variables don't survive across multiple evaluations. See: http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/RedBridge

To change this behaviour, set the `org.jruby.embed.localvariable.behavior` property:

```
    System.setProperty("org.jruby.embed.localvariable.behavior", "persistent");

    ScriptEngine engine = new JRubyEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
    LittleClass l = new LittleClass();
    engine.put("l", l);
    engine.eval("l.add");
    System.out.println(engine.eval("l.x"));
```